# Facebook android sdk can not import into workspace in eclipse

Tags: android

i downloaded the facebook android application example from github and imported it using the git plugin in eclipse.The issue arose when i wanted to import the android sdk to use it as a library...and got the "no projects to import" error, please how do i solve this?..thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by creating a new project from source. 
File -> New Project -> New Android Project -> Create project from existing source

and then use the directory where you downloaded the facebook sdk.

Comment: Ok ty for ur response...i tried that...and its still giving me...a "unable to find androidmanifest.xml" file..and how will i customize this option:"create project from source"...when i just want to include a call to the facebook sdk...

Comment: Are you sure you have downloaded the complete directory? You might want to download the sdk again.

Comment: This did not work for me, but the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9000707/786020) did.

Answer (score 0):

it is because u select the root of facebook sdk folder, go futher one level on facebook sdk directory and select facebook folder then you will not get androidmanifest.xml error. I'm h

Comment: "I'm h"? Please finish your answer.