# difficulty in importing the facebook-android-sdk into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, git

I try to follow the facebook-android tutorial from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sample
I am working in windows 7.
I have installed the Git and cloned the GitHub repository running this command in the git Bash -> git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git

Everything seemed fine and I got the folder “facebook-android-sdk” in my “Users” folder.

But when I try to import the project in eclipse workspace so to use it as a library I cannot make it work. I’ve tried 3 things:

1. Create the project from existing source (as the tutorial says), when I browse to the “facebook-android-sdk” folder and create the project, I get this message in my cosole: [2011-12-04 14:01:49 - com_facebook_android] AndroidManifest.xml file missing!
   Also in the package explorer, the src folder seems to be empty.
2. If I try to import the project when I browse the folder I get a message “No projects are found to import”
3. I also tried to make a test project where I copied all the classes of the android facebook sdk so that I can use them. It worked up to a degree, but it does not seem a proper thing to do.

So what do I do wrong? Is there something else I should do using the git repository (I am completely new to git)? Or is there something wrong that I do when I try to import the project? I’ve searched the problem here and in other forums but didn’t find a satisfying answer (or maybe I did not understand it). Please help!

EDIT: I've tried one 4th thing

4: I extracted the jar out of the project I created in 1 (even if it had an error). It is working in terms that I can compile the code of the facebook-android tutorial step 6.2 - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sample. So far it seems that everything goes ok. But I do not know if this is right or I should have problems in the future..

Comment: For me this problem started after I updated the Android stuff through Eclipse, I think Google broke something

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem. But now I think I solved it, even if the solution is not satisfying.
Create the project from existing source as the facebook tutorial says. Then make a right click on the project and choose "Import", choose "General" -> "File System" and go to "Next". Now click on "Browse..." and choose the folder .../facebook-android-sdk/facebook. Repeat these steps with the src and the res folder (right click on these folders for "Import", choosing the src and res folder in .../facebook-android-sdk/facebook).
Now it works. I don't know why Eclipse doesn't import all these things automatically, in the past it worked fine...

Comment: Thank you very much! I used to work it with a jar, but this is better. It is really strange that eclipse works this way

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you select the “facebook-android-sdk” folder you add **/facebook** at the end. So type into existing source C:/Users/facebook-android-sdk/facebook and it should work.

Comment: sorry for the late response.. I was using it with the jar and for some strange reason I didn't see your comment in my inbox. That's exactly what I import (or use to create project from existing source). But I still get "AndroidManifest.xml file missing!" error though the original folder contains an AndroidManifest.xml file..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your code's directory is dropped directly in Eclipse's root Workspace directory. There seems to be a bug in the latest version that only allows this kind of import/load when all code is directly in a directory in your Workspace. Otherwise it copies just a couple folders/files from where you put it, and not the rest, and gets quite confused.

Comment: i filed a bug (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26369) and found a work around - work around is to add the project into Eclipse's root workspace directory (as you mention), and then right click, refactor, move (and move it where you want).

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the file in zip format from the git directory. I created a android project, then i imported the zip archive (import ->archive file). It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import projects into Eclipse, you do not have to go down to the src folder, just do

`File > Import > Existing projects into Workspace`

then go to the directory where the folder is, say your Documents folder C:\users\Documents
then just click 'ok'
The window then displays all the folders in the Documents folder.
you can then select the project you want to import and click finish.