# Facebook SDK for Android Eclipse and Ubuntu installation

Tags: android, facebook, ubuntu, sdk

I am trying to set up eclipse on my Ubuntu 13.04 computer to be able to create apps for android. Right now I have the android sdk installed and working properly with eclipse and everything, but I know I'm going to want to integrate Facebook login into my app.

I have tried to search the web for instructions on how to do this with linux, but have so far turned up empty handed. If anyone could help that has gotten this working, or could link me to a website with good instructions, I would appreciate it.

P.S. I'm not sure if it is even possible. I hope it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375211/difficulty-in-importing-the-facebook-android-sdk-into-eclipse) questions answers. Download facebook android sdk and import facebook-android-sdk/facebook as a library project. Then add this library project into your project. Hope this helps.